# Keeping both microdata and microformats

Tags: html, microdata, microformats

I read that I should prefer putting in html code *Microdata* instead of *Microformats*, and actually I integrated both in my website.

Is it a bad practice keeping both? Should I have to remove the *Microformats* code?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No need to remove it.

Some consumers only look for Microformats, some consumers only look for Microdata, and those that look for both should¹ have no reason to get confused. The syntaxes [don’t share any mechanism](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/72691/17633), so there is no potential for conflicts.

---

¹ In the early days, [Google stated](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/166669/63183) that authors shouldn’t use both because "it may confuse the parser", but they revoked this shortly after.